# SQL: not showing the same date when given from and to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

When trying to get same date in between, it is just throwing an empty table.
My table structure is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblNames](
    [RorId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name1] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Name2] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RorId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and some data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] ([RorId], [Name1], [Name2], [BirthDate]) VALUES (1, N'A', N'A', CAST(N'2022-06-13T10:52:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] ([RorId], [Name1], [Name2], [BirthDate]) VALUES (2, N'C', N'E', CAST(N'2022-06-13T11:52:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] ([RorId], [Name1], [Name2], [BirthDate]) VALUES (3, N'C', N'E', CAST(N'2022-06-13T12:52:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] ([RorId], [Name1], [Name2], [BirthDate]) VALUES (4, N'E', N'C', CAST(N'2022-06-13T08:52:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblNames] OFF
GO
```

Comment: please do not post image. Post your query  in the question as text

Comment: Convert the string to date using cast or convert

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `BETWEEN SomeValue AND SomeValue` might as well be `= SomeValue`.

Comment: WHY do you store birthdate as datetime? And why do the values stored have seemingly random time values? Ultimately you have a schema problem you need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
select * from tblNames 
where BirthDate >= '2022-06-13 00:00:00' and BirthDate <= '2022-06-13 23:59:59'
```

**OR**

```
select * from tblNames
where BirthDate between '2022-06-13 00:00:00' and '2022-06-13 23:59:59'
```

**OR you can add milliseconds as below:**

```
select * from tblNames
where BirthDate between '2022-06-13 00:00:00.000' and '2022-06-13 23:59:59.997'
```

Be careful about `Time` part in `datetime` Data Type.

Comment: Why not use `>=` and `<` logic?

Comment: Hi @Larnu I Edited my answer and I add another type of SQL Script
` select * from tblNames
where BirthDate between '2022-06-13 00:00:00' and '2022-06-13 23:59:59' ` but if it is possible please explain more about logic. thanks so much.

Comment: Not sure what more I can explain... `>=` and `<` logic is exactly as it looks like: `SomeColumn >= SomeValue AND SomeColumn < AnotherValue`

Comment: you right @Larnu  and I tested  >+ and it works fine. Thanks for your information.

Comment: The precision of datetime is approximately 3 milliseconds, so the maximum time portion is 23:59:59.997. However unlikely it is for such a value to be stored, it is far better to avoid that precision issue and use an exclusive upper boundary like '20220614' (for this case). Your use of BETWEEN in the second example is **exactly the same** as the logic in the first.

Comment: You are right @SMor and I also added milliseconds to the code.